# How can I export a table to xml to include nested, repeated elements

Tags: xml

I have a table like so:

```
Award  |  Name     |  Amount
Gold   |  John     |   $5
Gold   |  Karen    |   $5
Gold   |  Clyde    |   $4
Silver |  Blake    |   $3
```

and I'm looking for an xml output like this: (so that the matching data in column 1 are treated as one element, with their corresponding data treated as repeating sibling elements

```
<prize>
 <award>gold</award>
 <awardee>
   <name>John</name>
   <amount>$5</amount>
 </awardee>
 <awardee>
   <name>Karen</name>
   <amount>$4</amount>
 </awardee>
 <awardee>
   <name>Clyde</name>
   <amount>$3/amount>
 </awardee>
</prize>
<prize>
 <award>silver</award>
 ...
```

The table originated from an access database, and was exported as csv. I've tried importing this schema into excel and export as xml, but the error thrown was along the lines of "cannot export xml due to list within lists." I would love even just a hint on how to go about this, but I'm lost on where to begin.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Are you familiar with any languages in particular?  This can be done in many different ways.

Comment: I'm most familiar with PHP. I guess the part that would throw me is how to do the FOREACH to grab all the like data in column 1.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a PHP guy, but I would be happy to show you a Java or C# option.  Looks like someone beat me to a Python example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are familiar with [Python](http://python.org/), you may want to look into the [lxml](http://lxml.de) module. Given that your data is in `my_data.csv` (comma separated values) and having a header line like in your example, this code should do the trick (tested with Python 2.7, but will probably work on most versions of Python).

```
from lxml import etree
from itertools import groupby
import csv

with open('my_data.csv') as data_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(data_file)
    f = lambda x: x['Award']
    data = sorted(list(reader), key=f)
    root = etree.Element('root')
    for k, g in groupby(data, key=f):
        prize = etree.SubElement(root, 'prize')
        award = etree.SubElement(prize, 'award')
        award.text = k
        for entry in g:
            awardee = etree.SubElement(prize, 'awardee')
            name = etree.SubElement(awardee, 'name')
            name.text = entry['Name']
            amount = etree.SubElement(awardee, 'amount')
            amount.text = entry['Amount']

    with open('my_data.xml', 'wb') as out_file:
        out_file.write(etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

The output is saved to `my_data.xml`, and looks like you want it (with an extra root tag).

```
<root>
  <prize>
    <award>Gold</award>
    <awardee>
      <name>John</name>
      <amount>$5</amount>
    </awardee>
    <awardee>
      <name>Karen</name>
      <amount>$5</amount>
    </awardee>
    <awardee>
      <name>Clyde</name>
      <amount>$4</amount>
    </awardee>
  </prize>
  <prize>
    <award>Silver</award>
    <awardee>
      <name>Blake</name>
      <amount>$3</amount>
    </awardee>
  </prize>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2):

XML at its core, does not have a pre defined behavior any where.

1. You need to define it **according to your style**
2. You also need to define a consuming code which acts for your business logic.(**according to your style**)

Being both is yourself. Okay, in your current problem, You need to put a parent element wrapped around the `<prize>`s. Otherwise, it throws an error as an xml as a basic rule, avoids   a root element more than one. (*And it SHOULD* contain a root element and which is one only one.)

Try to take care of this point while you are exporting from access or some such. If you have control over the access database, you can select a query like `SELECT CONCAT("<ROOT_ELEMENT>", YOUR DATA, "</ROOT_ELEMENT>")`... Or, before exporting from excel, add a root element and close it at the end. You need to somehow add a root element wrapped at least while inserting the data into the database.